# Check multiple inputs in the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, input

```
n_lines = int(input('How many lines do you want to input?'))

lines = [input() for i in range(n_lines)]
```

I want to break the loop if user hits 5 or any higher number.

Comment: What loop? I don't see one

Comment: Ok. What's preventing you from doing that? Surely you can write a loop with an `if` statement inside?

Comment: Do you mean the `for` loop inside the list comprehension?

Comment: @L3viathan The loop is inside the list. I don't know what its actually called.      lines = [input() for i in range(n_lines)]

Comment: @cdarke Yes, the loop inside the list. I also wanna check the input elements simultaneously.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I did try it. It doesn't work, if you have the solution please do share.

Comment: @ManishSingh, if you replace n_lines in the list comprehension with min(5,n_lines), at most 5 inputs will be asked from the user, even if n_lines is greater than 5

Comment: @ThijsW I wanna break when user enters 5 or any higher number. User is free to enter any number below 5.

Comment: Is that for an input in the first line, or in the loop?

Comment: @ThijsW In the loop: Expected out: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5- break.

Comment: Is list comprehension a necessity?

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension, you are running around in circles with it.  Do it first using an ordinary `for` (or `while`) loop.

Comment: @ThijsW Yes, that's how i will reduce the time complexity of the code.

Comment: That's not true. A regular for loop is not slower.

Comment: @ThijsW I have been using ordinary loops for past 2 years, Time to upgrade.

Comment: This can't be done with a list comprehension. (It *can* be done with *two* list comprehensions, but why do that instead of using a regular loop?)

Comment: Not necessarily faster with a list comprehension, its not that simple.  List comprehensions are not always the answer.  Benchmark your code before blindly changing it.

Comment: List comprehension can be really nice, but can also be unnecessarily complicated, like it is in this case.

Comment: Here's the list comprehension solution: `lines = [n for n in itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n < 5, (int(input()) for _ in range(n_lines)))]`. And yes, that's the best and shortest way to do that in a single line that I could come up with. I didn't purposely write bad code. If you still can't see that your way of doing it is bad, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: That's a beautifully horrible way of doing it @Aran-Fey ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the desired output:

```
n_lines = int(input('How many lines do you want to input?'))

lines = []
for i in range(n_lines):
    x = input()
    lines.append(x)
    if int(x) >= 5:
        break

print(lines)
```

Comment: Not what i am looking for.

Comment: @ManishSingh Why not?

Comment: @ManishSingh, this outputs exactly what you asked for. If this is not an acceptable solution for you, you really need to be clearer in describing what you are looking for.

Comment: I want it to be within one line.

Comment: @ManishSingh You want bad code? We don't post bad code here.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The code is given to enhance and not modify.

Comment: Guys, if you know the solution please post. Not here for an argument. I am here to learn something new, i would appreciate if you can help. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: @ManishSingh Nowhere in your question have you said that the solution must be a one-liner. Which is good, because writing this in a single line is horrible. Don't ask us to write bad code. This answer is a good solution. Let go of your arbitrary requirements.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, you guys are still stuck on the concepts of C-language which was introduced in 1972. Python is built to do complex task so lets make the most out of it.

Comment: @ManishSingh Can you just accept the advice of experienced pythonistas instead of trying to convince us that your way of doing things is better than ours by making weird comparisons with other programming languages?

Answer (score -1):

After much insistence on solving this in one line, I would do the same as this:

```
n_lines = int(input('How many lines do you want to input?'))
lines = [input() for i in range(5 if n_lines>5 else n_lines)]
```

**EDIT**:

I  misunderstood the question completely. What the OP asks seems impossible to me as whatever you do in the 2nd line just defines the range. You can't add more functionalities in the same line as of now (Maybe future versions of Python?).

The most optimal solution as also stated by others is,

```
n_lines = int(input('How many lines do you want to input?'));
lines=[]
for i in range(0,n_lines):
  n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  if n>=5:
    break
  lines.append(n)
print(lines)
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. They want the `[input() for i in range(n_lines)]` to stop taking input if an input is greater than 5.

Comment: Exactly. Is it possible to check while taking input ?

Comment: Contraints are on input for list memers not for  n_lines as per OP.

Comment: @mukeshkudi, Exactly. Do have  any solution to this? or Anyone who can provide one.

Comment: I think you should take @Aran-Fey suggestion. your requirement does not enhance or optimize the given solution by ThijsW.

Comment: @Nirmal, that's still not what OP wants. n_lines can be greater than 5, but as soon as the input() inside the list comprehension returns a value greater than 5, OP wants to break the loop.

Comment: My bad, I totally misunderstood the said question. What the OP is asking for is quite useless as there are much better ways to achieve this. @ThijsW answer is the most optimal.